# CXF Rest Client with Jackson provider // The expected result class in an interface

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have a rest service, and a client using CXF webservice proxy coming with Jackson mapper. For some reason, I have to design the result class as an interface. Something like following:

```
public interface SomeInterface {...}
```

and the proxy

```
@GET
@Path("/something/{id}")
public SomeInterface getById(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

SomeInterface will have several implementations. Now Jackson will complain that it cannot construct a new "SomeInterface" instance, yes, that's right.

But is there any way to tell Jackson to construct a concrete implementation of SomeInterface or not?

Thanks a lot,
KK

Comment: And what is your current proxy implementation?

Comment: hi, here the proxy I meant what on client side, CXF support creating a rest proxy from an interface. the implemetation just in server side... or did I misunderstand your question?